# YAML front matter in R markdown version 2: add an institution and logo

Tags: r, yaml, pandoc, r-markdown

Is it possible to add an institution and logo to the YAML front matter in R markdown version 2?

I'm looking for something like this

```
---
title:       "My report"
author:      "me"
institution: "Swansea University"
logo:        "logo.png"
output:
   pdf_document:
   toc: yes
---
```

Comment: I did try something like `author: "NAME SURNAME \\newline Swansea University"`, but this changes the text alignment terribly.

Comment: What if you used a template that incorporates a Beamer theme that uses a logo and institution? http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html

Comment: I think I'm probably better off to change the .tex template R Studio uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a template file, but it needs a bit of tweaking for the logo bit:

```
---
title:       "My report"
author:      "me"
output:
   pdf_document:
   toc: yes
   includes:
     in_header: style.tex
---
```

Prepare the document "style.tex" in the same folder as your markdown file and make sure you have changed you working directory in R to this folder.

Add the following lines to your "style.tex" file:

```
\institute{My institute}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=2cm]{logo}{logo.png}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\pgfuseimage{logo}}
```

Thanks to:
[Inserting logo into beamer presentation using R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890939/inserting-logo-into-beamer-presentation-using-r-markdown)